# Set up "sending from" warning on MS Outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have multiple email accounts linked to Outlook:

```
1. Gmail personal
2. Business XXX
3. Business YYY
```

Currently, default `From` option is my Gmail account. Sometimes I will need to send emails from different accounts. When I click on `Send` button, is there a way to set up a pop-up warning box to say that I am sending from chosen email account.

Essentially, I want to avoid sending email from `Business XXX` or `Gmail` to a colleague at `Business YYY`.